# Cannot add project in Timepiece (Django)

Tags: ajax, django

When i try to create a new project in Timepiece the project is added to my model as i can see in the backend but the view gives me a TemplateSyntaxError.

it states:

```
Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: settings.AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS not configured correctly for 'user'
```

the django docs give me that there is a setting missing in my settings.py. But i don't know which.

Excuse me if this is very obvious.

My traceback:

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/timepiece/project/13/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'pagination',
 'ajax_select',
 'timepiece',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/erp/apps/timepiece/templates/timepiece/project/view.html, error at line 41
   Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: settings.AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS not configured correctly for 'user'
   31 :                 <a title='Remove {{ user.get_full_name }}' href='{% url remove_user_from_project project_id=project.id,user_id=user.id %}?next={% url view_project project_id=project.id %}'><img alt='Remove {{ user.get_full_name }}' src='{{ FAMFAMFAM_URL }}/delete.png' /></a>


   32 :             {% endif %}


   33 :         </li>


   34 :     {% endfor %}


   35 :     {% endifnotequal %}


   36 :     </ul>


   37 :     {% if perms.timepiece.add_projectrelationship %}


   38 :     <form id="add-user" action='{% url add_user_to_project project_id=project.id %}?next={% url view_project project_id=project.id %}' method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">


   39 :         {% csrf_token %}


   40 :         <div class="field-wrapper">


   41 :              {{ add_user_form }} 


   42 :             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" id="submit" />


   43 :         </div>


   44 :     </form>


   45 :     {% endif %}


   46 : </div>


   47 : 


   48 : <table class='vertical'>


   49 :     <tr>


   50 :         <th>Type:</th>


   51 :         <td>{{ project.type }}</td>


Traceback:
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  217.                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/erp/apps/timepiece/utils.py" in wrapper
  63.                     context_instance=RequestContext(request),
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  188.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  123.             return self._render(context)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  311.             return self.nodelist_true.render(context)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
  92.             output = force_unicode(output)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_unicode
  71.                 s = unicode(s)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __unicode__
  95.         return self.as_table()
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_table
  217.             errors_on_separate_row = False)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _html_output
  180.                     'field': unicode(bf),
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __unicode__
  408.         return self.as_widget()
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_widget
  439.         return widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ajax_select/fields.py" in render
  35.         lookup = get_lookup(self.channel)
File "/Users/Bair1/virtualenvs/erp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ajax_select/__init__.py" in get_lookup
  115.         raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS not configured correctly for %r" % channel)

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /timepiece/project/13/
Exception Value: Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: settings.AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS not configured correctly for 'user'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using `django_ajax_selects` project which requires a setting `AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNEL` in your main `settings.py` that maps models to fields. Something like:

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'person'  : {'model':'example.person', 'search_field':'name'}
}
```

(from it's docs)